# ARM Translation for Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

I am having trouble running a game app on Genymotion. It runs find with bluestacks and not so well known droid4x.

I have searched and read numerous forums and I still am no closer to finding a solution.

My conclusions are:

1. It details in the logcat that it maybe be a OpenGL problem.
2. People have pointed to an outdated ARM Translation.
3. I cannot find anything on who compiles the ARM Translation and/or libhoudini

The so called game app is Star Wars Force Collection. I'm just frustrated why it works on other emulators and not genymotion.

Any suggestions and advice would be appreciated